# php - Can't send form with special characters character

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm working on a contact form for my website and I'm trying to make the user submit their email and name through an HTML form. My form has a reCaptcha and here is the `action` file:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])):
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
            // Your site secret key
            $secret = 'my_secret_key';
            // Remote user address
            $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            // Get verify response data
            $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
            $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
            if($responseData->success):
                // Contact form submission code
                $email = htmlentities(!empty($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'');

                $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
                $subject = 'A new email from ' . $email;
                $htmlContent = '<p><a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $email . '</a></p>';

                // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                // More headers
                $headers .= 'From: User <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
                // Send email
                @mail($to, $subject, $htmlContent, $headers);
                @mail($email, $subject, $htmlContent, $headers);
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;
?>
```

So if the user submits an @ (at) in their email field, the email never gets sent. I suspect it could be because of the above code. Are there any kind of restrictions to which characters can be sent/accepted by `mail`? And if so why? I tried sending a message like this:

адгтф~`!#$%^&*()_-+=<,>.?/:;"'\|{}[]

And it never got to my email-box. Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `@` before the `mail` function to get any notices / warning / errors from it.

Comment: Don't do `htmlentities($email)`, you must have a properly formatted email for the `mail()` function, and this turns it into HTML characters.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I did not see any messages from php after removing the `@`. @Anton I thought it was a good idea to help protect the site from server-side attacks... But I'll remove it, if that's advisable.

Comment: I fixed it. And I don't even know how... Well I don't care as long as it works :D Thanks anyways.